# Is it ok to add [UPDATE] to a question's title after a major revision

Tags: discussion, edits, title

The programming rookie I am, I sometimes ask questions where I only later realise that I missed the problem somewhat. E.g.

**Q**: Why won't my toast get toasted?
**A**: You'll have to plug in the toaster.
**Q [UPDATE]**: Why won't my toast get toasted even when plugging in the toaster?

In smaller communities like GIS or AskDifferent it often happens that the pro users then miss my question, because they won't bother to read it again after an edit.

By adding "[UPDATE]" at the end of the question title I could indicate that there has been a change to my question.

Another effective method would be to delete and ask a new question, but sometimes there were already some good answers pointing in the right direction. It would be a pity to loose those.

Comment: Why does this question deserve a downvote?

Comment: In meta a down vote does not mean the question is bad - it means that the voter disagrees with the question

Comment: This is a valid discussion, but people just don't agree with the idea itself of changing the title as you describe.

Answer (score 21):

No, it's not OK.

On Stack Exchange, we detect changes by last activity and revisions.

For example, it's easy to detect edits in the front page by looking for "modified" label:

> [image]

And clicking the "modified" even brings us [directly to the edited post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166225/zoomin-to-feature-with-ol3/166482#166482).

No need to clutter the front page with noise.

Answer (score 11):

When a question is updated it goes back to the top of the active questions list so anybody looking at that list (which is anybody trying to answer questions on that tag) knows it's been edited.

There's no point therefore in adding [UPDATE] in fact it actively harms readability.

As to deleting the original and adding a new question. If there are answers to the old question and you want to ask something that would invalidate those answers then that won't fly so be careful doing that. Instead, take the time to make the question the best it can be in the first place.

You can always ask a follow up question if you need to referencing your original question if the answers you're getting are not what you want.

Comment: That's what follow up questions are for. No need to edit the original, that may still prove useful to someone else.

Comment: Oh did you update the answer or did I just miss that?

Comment: There's a grace period on posts where edits' are just merged into the original. I changed it before your comment, but not necessarily before you read the original.

Comment: It's known as "ninja edits". /cc @n1000. :-)